# PHP E-mail Form Sender Name Instead Of E-mail?

Tags: php, html, css

Right now, I've set up a PHP e-mail form and everything works fine.  However, while testing it, I'm only getting the sender e-mail address as the name.  What I want is the name of the sender, like:

John Doe

Subject Subject Subject

Instead of:

j.doe@website.com

Subject Subject Subject

Below is the code...

Can someone help me please?  Thanks.

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "ricky@rickytsang.ca";
    $email_subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['full_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $full_name = $_POST['full_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message= $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The e-mail you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$full_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($message) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The message you entered doee not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "E-mail: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Right after your 4 lines that say `$email_message .= ...` add a line:

```
$email_from = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';
```

Comment: @BugWhisperer Then you're doing something else wrong, like setting Fom to use a custom domain name without setting up DKIM.

Comment: nah my dkim and spf are all good. but `$from = "From: Name <name@email.com";` causes it to be flagged as spam, whereas `From = "name@email.com";` works like a charm. strange i know. not ALL the time, but frequently

Answer (score 14):

THen you need it in this form:

```
"John Doe <j.doe@website.com>"
```

Comment: formatting this way makes my emails get marked as spam

Comment: @BugWhisperer Then you probably sending spam.

Comment: obviously not, otherwise it would make sense as to why it's being marked as spam...

Answer (score 3):

Usualy you simply need to reformat the from address like this:

```
"Ricky, Dear" <dearricky@yahoo.com>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: It doesn't matter... same format!  Who cares who's name you put there... yours or anyone else's.

Comment: No, I'm saying when I receive the e-mail, I want to see the name of the person who filled out the form.

Comment: `$from="\"" . $_POST['full_name'] . "\" <" . $_POST['email'] . ">";`  It probably wouldn't hurt to validate both prior to generating such a message header.

Comment: @DearRicky. Brad is giving you the format in which you need to convert email address in header to. I've added its implementation below in my answer.

Comment: Teach a man to fish....  DearRicky, you wrote this script, yes?  You see the part where you create your headers?  There is a line there where you set where the e-mail is from.  That is where you will want to put **where the e-mail is from**.  The code I just posted in these comments *concatenates* (sticks together) the pieces in the proper format.

Comment: Lol, I actually have no idea how to write code.  I got this off the web and edited it with a bit of trial and error.

Comment: formatting this way makes my emails get marked as spam

Answer (score 3):

In the headers you must set the From header like this:

```
<?php
...
$headers = 'From: ' . clean_string($full_name) . ' <' . clean_string($email_from) . ">\r\n";
..
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you stimms!

So, your whole code portion would look like this:

```
// prepare email body text
$message = "";

$message .= "Thanks for registering .....";

$message .= "\n";

$message .= "More stuff here";

$headers = "From: John Smith <info@yourcoolsite.com>";


mail($recipientemail, "Hey thanks for joining!", $message, $headers);
```

Then the email recipient will see an email in their inbox that looks like this:

FROM: John Smith

SUBJECT: Hey thanks for joining!

MESSAGE: Thanks for registering ..... More stuff here

Answer (score 1):

You set the e-mail address like this

```
$email_to = "Ricky <ricky@rickytsang.ca>";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: No, I'm saying when I receive the e-mail, I want to see the name of the person who filled out the form.

Comment: Please, Did you ever get a working solution ? ... having the same problems, marked as spam.

Answer (score 1):

change these 4 lines

```
 $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message= $_POST['message'];
```

to:

```
 $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message= '"' . $full_name . '" <' . $_POST['message'] . '>';
```

please make sure u copy paste this as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal e-mail Form Sender Name Instead Of E-mail with Domain Basis?

Example:

```
function hook_mail_alter(&$message) {

if($message['id'] == "put_id" && $domain_id == 368){

$default_from = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));

if($message['from'] == $default_from){

$message['from'] = '"'. variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal') .'" <'. 
$default_from .'>';

$message['headers']['From'] = $message['from'];

}

}

}
```